# Why is my if statement in my program not working?

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to make a program so when 2 switches are flipped they light up two 4 pin LEDs, but only when both switches are flipped. I'm trying to make a cool BattleBots arena and thought something like that would be cool to have as a starting sequence! If you spot any extra errors feel free to correct me.

```
int buttonPin = 13;
int buttonPin2 = 3;
int counter = 0;

int redpin = 11; //select the pin for the red LED
int bluepin =10; // select the pin for the  blue LED
int greenpin =9;// select the pin for the green LED

int redpin2 = 7; //select the pin for the 2 red LED
int bluepin2 =6; // select the pin for the 2 blue LED
int greenpin2 =5;// select the pin for the 2 green LED


int pinButton = 13; //the pin where we connect the button

int pinButton2 = 3; //the pin where we connect the button

int val;
 
void setup() {

  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT);
  pinMode(redpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluepin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redpin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluepin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenpin2, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
 
void loop() 

 { int buttonState;
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  int buttonState2;
  buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);
 }

int main()
  
  if (buttonState == LOW && buttonState2 == LOW);
   analogWrite(11, 0);
   analogWrite(10, 225);
   analogWrite(9,  0);
   delay(5); 

   analogWrite(7, 0);
   analogWrite(6, 225);
   analogWrite(5, 0);
   delay(5); 
  
  }else{
   analogWrite(11, 225);
   analogWrite(10, 0);
   analogWrite(9,  0);
   delay(5); 

   analogWrite(7, 0);
   analogWrite(6, 0);
   analogWrite(5, 225);
   delay(5);
  }
```

Comment: I think you are missing a `{` right after `main()`

Comment: you can't use function named 'main' in arduino sketch

Answer (score 0):

Your code seem to be a cut and paste from several sources, here's what it should look like, I added notes in the code:

```
const int buttonPin = 13;
const int buttonPin2 = 3;

const int redpin = 11; //select the pin for the red LED
const int bluepin = 10; // select the pin for the  blue LED
const int greenpin = 9; // select the pin for the green LED

const int redpin2 = 7; //select the pin for the 2 red LED
const int bluepin2 = 6; // select the pin for the 2 blue LED
const int greenpin2 = 5; // select the pin for the 2 green LED

/*
  Unused variables removed:
  int counter = 0;
  int pinButton = 13;
  int pinButton2 = 3;
  int val;
*/


void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(redpin, OUTPUT);
  /*
    Depending on your hardware you may want to pull-up the button pins:
    pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  */
  
  pinMode(bluepin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redpin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluepin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenpin2, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int buttonState;
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  int buttonState2;
  buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);
  
  /*
   main() function had several issues, it was a function returning an integer without 
   any return statement and it is never called by your code. Looks like it should be 
   part of loop() like so:
  */
  
  if (buttonState == LOW && buttonState2 == LOW) {
    analogWrite(11, 0);
    analogWrite(10, 225);
    analogWrite(9,  0);
    delay(5);

    analogWrite(7, 0);
    analogWrite(6, 225);
    analogWrite(5, 0);
    delay(5);

  } else {

    analogWrite(11, 225);
    analogWrite(10, 0);
    analogWrite(9,  0);
    delay(5);

    analogWrite(7, 0);
    analogWrite(6, 0);
    analogWrite(5, 225);
    delay(5);
  }
}
```

Comment: No problems, you are welcome to upvote and select the answer